# List children in android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android Programming. I want to list all child lists from Firebase in Android.

I wrote this code. But When I start the application, the listview returns null.

What am doing wrong?

```
public class haber_goruntule extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView liste;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_haber_goruntule);
    final List<connector_haber> mesajlar=new ArrayList<connector_haber>();

    liste= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref=firebaseDatabase.getReference();

    ref.child("haberler").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children=dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for(DataSnapshot child : children){

             connector_haber haber=child.getValue(connector_haber.class);
                mesajlar.add(haber);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    final ArrayAdapter<connector_haber> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<connector_haber>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mesajlar);
    liste.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hello @Kevin. Please make sure you actually receive the data in onDataChange using debug mode or log statements. Also please add `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` call as a last line in onDataChange callback

Comment: you can use child listener as well https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener that way you dont need the iterator but have to add the data to the adapter each time is added

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time it comes back, you're adding it to the adapter, but Android isn't aware of that anymore. To make it aware, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you've added the data:

```
final ArrayAdapter<connector_haber> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<connector_haber>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mesajlar);
liste.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
ref.child("haberler").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> children=dataSnapshot.getChildren();
        for(DataSnapshot child : children){

            connector_haber haber=child.getValue(connector_haber.class);
            mesajlar.add(haber);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // tell the adapter to update the view

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore this error
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank  I added   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() .But it stills shows nothing. My database "haberler" has subchildren which has its own keys.Do you think I am using the right way to list the database in a listview?

Comment: That's hard for me to see from here. But you can step through your `onDataChange()` method in a debugger and see if `haber` has the values you expect it to have. If not, it's likely that your `connector_haber` class doesn't match with your JSON model (which seems like a separate question to me).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
   ref.child("haberler").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> children=dataSnapshot.getChildren();
        for(DataSnapshot child : children){

            connector_haber haber=child.getValue(connector_haber.class);
            mesajlar.add(haber);
        }
       final ArrayAdapter<connector_haber> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<connector_haber>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mesajlar);
       liste.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore this error
    }
});
```

Comment: @Kevin check this

Answer (score 0):

well.. there is an open source library for implementing UI with firebase. Try this one [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

Comment: While that is definitely a valid approach, it is also valid to build a custom adapter. In fact, that's pretty much how FirebaseUI started: after building custom adapters for a few years, we realized it might be useful to put them in a reusable library.

Comment: Ohhooo.. man @Frank you are awesome.. I've seen your profile! I'm very impressed !! hatz off